# DynamoDb persist items for a specific time

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have this flow in which we have to persist in DynamoDb some items for a specific time. After the items has expired, we have to call some other services, to notify them that data got expired.

I was thinking about two solutions:

**1)** Move expiry check to Java logic:
Retrieve DynamoDb data in batches, verify the expiry items in Java, and after that delete the data in batches, and notify other services.

There are some limitations:

**BatchGetItem** let you retrieve **max 100 items.**
**BatchWriteItem** let you delete **max 25 items**

**2)** Move expiry check to the db logic:
**Query** the DynamoDb, in order to check which items has expired(and delete them), and return the id's to the client, in order for us to notify other services.

Again, there are some limitations:

The result set from a Query **is limited to 1 MB** per call.

For both solutions, there will be a job, that will be run periodically, or we're going to use some aws lambda that will be triggered periodically and will call an endpoint from our app that is going to delete the item from db and notify other services.

My question is if DynamoDb is proper for my case, or should I use some relational db that doesn't have these kind of limitations like Mysql? What do you think ? Thanks!

Comment: Beyond what other people answered, please note that if you want an application to read all the data (to check for expired data), BatchGetItem is the wrong API to use. Instead, you should use Scan, which allows you to page through the entire data or just specific attributes of each item. You can also use Scan in parallel from many nodes.

Comment: Ok, so you're saying that I should use Scan with a filter of expiration. The only disadvantage that I saw is that scan is limited to 1MB of data retrieval, before the filter expression being applied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered using the [DynamoDB TTL feature](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/TTL.html)?  This allows you to create a time-based column in your table that DynamoDB will use to automatically delete the items based on the time value.

This requires no implementation on your part and no polling, querying, or batching limitations.  You will need to populate a TTL column but you may already have that information present if you are rolling your own expiration logic.

If other services need to be notified when a TTL event occurs, you can create a [Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.html) that processes a [DynamoDB stream](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html) and take action when a [TTL delete event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/time-to-live-ttl-streams.html) occurs.

Comment: Just a note that TTL does not mean row will be deleted exactly at that time. It may take some more time than TTL.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But in our case, items expiry based on different times. Not sure at this moment if we can configure different expiry times with TTL.

Comment: I'm not sure at this moment if DynamoDb is the best fit in my case..Some colleagues suggested to use Mysql and create a query that deleted the expiry items, and after that use a lambda to call my service, and from there we can notify the other services. Or should I use like a simple cron job, to do all that stuff, and NOT using the aws lambda ? What do you think ?

Comment: @brebDev you can set the TTL at the row level so you should be able to set different expire times for each row.  AWS Lambda can be triggered on scheduled basis like a cron job via a [Cloud Watch Event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html).  In my opinion, your expiration requirement alone is not a valid reason to choose MySQL over DynamoDB. A valid reason for choosing MySQL is if you need ACID transactions or if you have a very relational data model and require lots of joins.

Comment: The disadvantage of TTL is that it deletes expired items within 48 hours of expiration. What do you think for the case in which we need to notify other services, exactly when the items expired ? Nadav Har'El, in the comment above, suggest to scan the table with pagination. What do you think about that ?

Comment: Scanning can be costly and can chew through your read throughput if you do it frequently.  You could consider creating a global secondary index on your expiration date column.  This will allow you to do queries instead of scans which will be much performant and use much less read throughput. Regardless, you will still need to handle paging results of a query as it pages similar to a scan.  Most SDKs have paginators and/or iterators to make going through the pages easier.

Comment: Yes, you're right query use much less read throughput. Maybe I can use only limit(in order to limit query items returned) without any pagination. Or were you referring that it's a must to use the pagination ? BTW appreciate all your answers ! Thanks man :)

Comment: No problem, I enjoy helping.  You should always have code to handle multiple pages.  Even if you bump up the limit to a high number, there are other factors that may cause multiple pages such as the 1MB result size.  Handling multiple pages is not too difficult, it's easy to try and avoid it but it will come and bite you later.

Comment: Hey @JDD . I was busy with some other work, and this week I came back on this, and I was happy that I can do a GSI with partitionKey on expiryTransactionTime as you've suggested. I did that, but UNFORTUNATELY I could not make a query like: query index, where `expiryTransactionTime<Date.from(Instant.now())`. It seems that I'm only able to query the GSI with a MATCH condition on partitionKey :( . This changes everything..Not sure what to do in this moment.